# How to run estimator.train without saving checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm looking for a way to implement a search of learning rate as described here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01186.pdf .

My network is implemented using estimator api and I'd like to stick to that, but unfortunately I'm not able to force estimator to skip saving checkpoints. Do you know a way to simply run a one epoch o training without saving the checkpoints?

Answer (score 6):

According to the docs [tf.estimator.RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig):

> If both save_checkpoints_steps and save_checkpoints_secs are None, then checkpoints are disabled

So the code is following:

```
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=None,
                                    save_checkpoints_secs=None)
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, config=run_config)
```

Comment: It does not work with `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` I get the error: `ValueError: There should be a CheckpointSaverHook to use saving_listeners. Please set one of the RunConfig.save_checkpoints_steps or RunConfig.save_checkpoints_secs.` You have to use it with the `estimator.train` method.

Comment: @RicardoMS I had the same issue, it seems that `save_checkpoints_secs` cannot be set to `None` or `0`. Passing it through **kwargs if non-null worked for me.