# How to block estimator from restore weights and global steps for each training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to use tensorflow high-level API to develop a model and I find a issue in training and visualization phase:

For the same model_fn(), every time I try to invoke the estimator.train() method, the global_step will increase from the steps I trained last time. e.g., if run estimator.train() method last time to march to global_step = 2000, then this time when i start training the model, it will be accumulative starting from 2000, 2001, 2002...

My issue is: for some reason, I want to train a model from scratch every single time. that is to say, I don't need estimator to restore the previously-trained weights when i launch a training again.

Currently, I just manually delete the checkpoints and event files before launching a new training every time, and its truly inefficient. However, even so, there still exists residual curves about last time that I can not delete this way.

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

model_dir option in the estimator is where you provide the path to save the model(checkpoints and other stuff). So every time you start the training it looks that path and see if there are any checkpoints and if so it will pick the last checkpoint and load the weights into the model and starts training and that's why every time checkpoints increases.

It seems there is a way to completely stop saving the checkpoints please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361703/how-to-run-estimator-train-without-saving-checkpoints).

I currently give a new location to the model_dir path every time i wanted to start a new training. I will check if the path exists if not i will create that folder.